# Log4j not functioning

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

How to get the kafka streams work with log4j?  For example, doing below doesn't produce any output in the console

```
public class Streamtest{
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Streamtest.class.getName());
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       logger.debug("In main");
```

Log4j properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p [%t] %m (%c)%n
```

Run command

```
java -cp /tmp/Streamtest.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/kafka/libs/* -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/tmp/kafka_jaas.conf org.cox.test.Streamtest -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/tmp/log4j.properties
```

Corrected command

```
java -cp /tmp/Streamtest.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/kafka/libs/* -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/tmp/kafka_jaas.conf -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/tmp/log4j.properties org.cox.test.Streamtest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured myself, see above corrected command. The property argument should be kept first and then the main class. silly mistake !